# Why my google map is always not centered?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

While I can display, my setcenter/pointer is always at the to left position 0,0.
Why is that so?

Is there something I did not do correctly?
Cheers.

```
function initializeGMap() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width = $('#gmap').width() + "px";
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = $('#gmap').height() + "px";
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        var malllat = localStorage.getItem("malllat");
        var malllon = localStorage.getItem("malllon");
        var point = new GLatLng(malllat, malllon);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        map.setCenter(point, 16);
    }
}


<div data-role="page" id="gmap">
    <div id="mapheader" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#mall" class="getLocalStorage" data-icon="back" data-transition="none">Back</a>
        <h1>Google Map</h1>
    </div>
    <!--div id="map_canvas" style="width: 480px; height: 480px"></div-->
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you get the malllat and malllon from? Are you sure that they are > 0?

Comment: It is value I saved in localStorage. The map location and pointer are displayed correctly just the setCenter did not place it in the center of the Div.

Comment: According to the documentation you should call setCenter first http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.Methods.Modify-the-Map-State . Don't know if that is the reason but worth a try maybe.

Comment: Björn :) I did tried that before same result.

Comment: BTW, you should consider switching to Maps API V3, V2 is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I change to Maps API V3 and it centered correctly and the map loading is so much faster :)